# Drawing in 2D using a reference image, strokes keep appearing behind the reference image

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I'm using Blender 2.82, I'm drawing using a reference image but the strokes keep appearing behind the image, how do I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The option to **solve** your problem can be found in the **Object Data Properties** of the reference image object like in the picture below:
[image]
*to get there you need to switch in object mode and select the image reference object*

There is also an option to set the reference image to be in the front, BUT using transparency.
[image]

Happy Blending